# Webpack compiling CSS into strange classnames

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am currently using `webpack` while developing React app with a NodeJS backend.

I am having trouble with styling the app because it seems webpack trying to do something with my css where it ends up changing the classnames.

For instance in my `base.css` file I have this:

```
body {
  background: #ECEFF1;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;  
  max-width: 980px;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #FFECB3;
}
.progress .indeterminate {
    background-color: #FFC107;
}
```

Which when I load the page and look in the head is converted to a `<style>` div with these classnames:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background: #ECEFF1;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;  
  max-width: 980px;
}

.base---progress---1RR8Z {
  background-color: #FFECB3;
}
.base---progress---1RR8Z .base---indeterminate---23sZH {
    background-color: #FFC107;
}
```

So progress styles aren't being picked up on the page because they are changed into this format. How can I avoid this or have React change the class names appropriately?

---

If I removed this from my webpack config:

```
{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
    }
```

Line it says that it can't find the css file but the path it errors out on is valid.

---

Webpack config for good measure:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.join(__dirname, 'public/app/main.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/app/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "react-hmre"]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Rather than throw away `css-modules` from your workflow, it will be better for you to prepare for the future of CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config currently uses [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). To disable it
change `'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'` to `'style!css'` in  the loader for `css` files.